# Combine three arrays into one for insertion mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I'm at my wits end. I have a page which should insert a couple of arrays into a database. I'm trying to combine the arrays and insert them. I am not succeeding in combining them. 
Perhaps they do not even have to be combined, just inserted in an empty db. 
They all have the same keys, i'll list 3:

I have:

```
$reference_array contains:
(
[2815] => ref1
[2818] => ref2
[2835] => ref3
)

$ean_array contains:
(
[2815] => 6876876873
[2818] => 0097789783
[2835] => 0907678989
)

$price_array contains:
Array 
(
[2815] => 63.83
[2818] => 80.92
[2835] => 23.05
)
```

With one array I use explode() and the proper formatting for inserting into Mysql, but I cannot format multiple arrays in a way for insertion like below. I tried insert into in 3 different queries, but learned the data is appended in the db.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO data (Reference,EAN,Price) VALUES (the-reference-array,the-ean-array,theprice-array,etc,etc )";
```

It feels en looks simple, probably is. But not for me at this moment:-/

I've used things like:

```
$merged = array_combine(array_keys($reference),$reference);
$merged1 = $merged + array_combine($merged,$ean_array);
```

How can I combine these arrays and/or make a query for insertion so all arrays are 'aligned' to use the same key? All arrays have the same length, always.

Comment: How does your db schema look like? It's hard to help you if we do not know what format they need to be in

Comment: I omitted db scheme to keep it short. But it is ID INT 11, Reference VARCHAR 255 ,EAN INT 11, Price VARCHAR (for now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all three arrays always have exactly the same keys, you could do the following:

```
foreach (array_keys($price_array) as $key) {
    $reference = $reference_array[$key];
    $ean = $ean_array[$key];
    $price = $price_array[$key];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (Reference, EAN, Price) VALUES ('$reference', '$ean', $price)");
}
```

It's better to use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). That would look something like

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO data (Reference, EAN, Price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")

foreach (array_keys($price_array) as $key) {
    $statement->bind_param("ssd", $reference_array[$key], $ean_array[$key], $price_array[$key]);
    $statement->execute()
}
```

EDITED: Merged three `bind_param` calls to one. Thanks, @kingkero!

Comment: My bad, fixed it. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Btw, you can just use `foreach ($price_array as $key => $price) { ... }`.

Comment: I know, but since I'd need to get the other values using `$key` anyway, thought it might be good to get all the values in a similar manner.

Comment: @KaarelNummert You can shorten the `bind_param()` by setting `"ssd"`, saves 2 redundant lines ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO data (Reference,EAN,Price) VALUES ";
$comma = "";
foreach(array_keys($reference_array) as $key) {
  $sql.= $comma."('".$reference_array[$key]."', '".$ean_array[$key]."', '".$price_array[$key]."')";
  $comma = ", ";
}
```